# CreateJS cannot remove Event Handler

Tags: createjs

I have searched stackoverflow for a solution to this but nothing has worked.
I don't see why it shouldn't. My code looks as such:

A preloaded eventListener:

```
obj.container.on("click", Capture, null, false, [data]);

function Capture(evt, data){
}
```

this works as expected.
Now if I want to remove it with a condition:

```
if(state){
obj.container.off("click", Capture);
}
```

Does not work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the docs. The `on` method returns a closure, which is used to maintain scope. You must use that instead to remove the listener.

`var closure = obj.on("click", listener);
obj.off("click", closure);`

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_on